# Wordpress post (archive) filters dynamically?

Tags: wordpress, filter, widget

How to dynamically filter category, tags and date (both month and year)? Not possible with the default Wordpress widget, and i didnt found any plugin.

Comment: For example, if you select a date, also filter the category dropdown, and only select a category that exists in the selected year.

I found a solution for the category-date pair, but it's not enough.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.